# C++11 dependency injection in constructor with reference

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

Consider following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

class Sub{};

class SubImpl : public Sub {};

class A{
public:
    A(Sub & sub) : sub(sub){}

    void doSomething(){
        // ...
    };

private:
    Sub & sub;
};

std::unique_ptr<A> factory(){
    SubImpl sub;

    return std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(sub));
}

int main(){
    auto a = factory();

    a->doSomething();
}
```

This code have problem - Sub object lifetime is not same as A object, and `A::sub` reference is dangled.

In order to fix this, I can do:

- pass by value
- pass by const reference
- use `unique_ptr` / `shared_ptr` or to use raw pointer

Is there any other way I can fix this?

Comment: why not make A create Sub as an inner-object?

Comment: because I want to be able to pass child of Sub. I will edit.

Comment: what is wrong with your fixes?

Comment: if A absolutly needs to come from outside then `factory` will have to get it as an argument. although, the whole design seems a bit weird.

Comment: @m.s. I used to work with C++ in 2000's and then we used only raw pointers. Now everyone say we should use references and I am exploring possibilities.

Comment: @DavidHaim - I do not see anything weird. This is over-simplified example. Suppose factory() doing lots of work to construct the object. Object have several dependencies and so on. Finally instead to construct the object manually, you just call factory().

Comment: I see why you might need a `unique_ptr<Sub>` but is there any reason why factory is returning  `unique_ptr<A>` and not just `A` by value?

Comment: @ChrisDrew - this is good point, but in "real" code I need it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `unique_ptr` if the object `sub` is used solely to create only one `A` object. Use `shared_ptr` otherwise.

```
class Sub{};

class SubImpl : public Sub {};

class A{
public:
    A(std::unique_ptr &&sub) : sub(std::move(sub)){}

    void doSomething(){
        // ...
    };

private:
    std::unique_ptr sub;
};

std::unique_ptr<A> factory(){
    auto sub = std::make_unique<SubImpl>();;

    return std::make_unique<A>(std::move(sub));
}

int main(){
    auto a = factory();

    a->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: but not credible way do do it with references?

Comment: No. Because with references you can't control the life span of the object. There is nothing wrong with using pointers - especially smart pointers - when the use is justified. And the use here is justified. The overhead for `unique_ptr` is minimal, neglectable. For `shared_ptr` there is more overhead.

Comment: I think you should make it clear that `Sub` should have a `virtual` destructor for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have two choices, either the lifetime of `SubImpl` is controlled by `A` in which case I see no alternative to using a pointer,  preferably a `unique_ptr`, like  bolov has shown. And I don't think there is anything particularly wrong with that.

Or the lifetime of `SubImpl` is controlled by something outside of `A` in which case you *can* use references.

For example, you could change the factory so that it is an object that owns the `SubImpl`. Here is a simplistic example:

```
// definitions of Sub, SubImpl and A as before... 

class SubOwner {
    SubImpl sub;
public:
    A createA() const {
        return A(sub);
    }
};

int main(){
    SubOwner so;
    auto a = so.createA();
    a.doSomething();
}
```

That's fine if you only want one `SubImpl` but it is possible that you want to use your factory to create many `A`s and each `A` should have a reference to a different  `SubImpl`. In which case you could have an object that owns a collection of `SubImpl`:

```
class SubOwner {

    // Using deque instead of vector to avoid reference invalidation. 
    // Could use vector if you knew how many SubImpl you need up front. 
    std::deque<SubImpl> subs;
public:
    A createA() const {
        subs.emplace_back();
        return A(subs.back());
    }
};

int main(){
    SubOwner so;
    auto a1 = so.createA();
    auto a2 = so.createA();

    a1.doSomething();
    a2.doSomething();
}
```

Providing `SubOwner` and `A` are themselves owned by the same object or local to the same scope then you can guarantee that the lifetime of `SubImpl` will be the same as `A`.

Comment: this is interesting approach, i can even do it with singleton "thing" because I am actually making "strategy" pattern. Is this kind of ownership commonly used? also what would be google keyword so I can search for this ownership "schemes"?